# Find records in between two dates by only year and month MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch records based on month name and year from MySQL table. We have input e.g. month=January and Year=2015 and I want to check if January 2015 included in between start_date 12-Dec-2014 and end_date 20-Feb-2015

**MySQL Query**

```
SELECT * FROM `job_post` 
WHERE  employer_id = '4' AND job_end_date >= CURDATE() 
  AND  job_start_date BETWEEN '2014-12-30' AND '2015-02-15'
  AND  status = '1' AND repost = '0' AND is_delete = '0'
```

But this does not return proper result.

Comment: It has two different input for both month and year and I have only one input for month and year e.g. January for month and 2015 as year

Comment: Presently what you are getting output from that query?

Comment: @Rajnikanth, that doesn't really change things - it's still a duplicate. You have the same value for start and end of the range. Also "does not return proper result" is not a very useful description. What do you get, and what do you want?

Comment: @Vamshi.goli currently it does not return any records.

Comment: can you check the datatype of job_end_date and job_start_date?

Comment: Finally found solution SELECT * FROM `job_post` `t` WHERE employer_id = '4' AND job_end_date >= CURDATE() AND '2014-january' BETWEEN date_format(job_start_date, '%Y-%m') AND date_format(job_end_date, '%Y-%m') AND status = '1' AND repost = '0' AND is_delete = '0'